# Strange error with Prepared query is not of type SELECT_LONG

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I want to ask how can I make queries for this. I want to check the name from edit text and if the name exsist, as a part of record, in db i want to fill all edit texts with data from this object. Also I've got very strange error. Please help or give me an advice how to start with it. Im beginner. Thanks for all answers and clues.

Here is my code:

```
if(et_nazwa!=null){


             long value = 0;
            try {
                PreparedQuery<Klient> query = klientDao.queryBuilder()
                        .where().eq("Kli_nazwa",et_nazwa.getText().toString()).prepare();
                value = klientDao.countOf(query);
            } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                try {
                    if(value!=0){

                    PreparedQuery<Klient> q_adres = klientDao.queryBuilder().selectColumns("Kli_adres").where().eq("Kli_nazwa",et_nazwa.getText().toString()).prepare();
                    PreparedQuery<Klient> q_nip = klientDao.queryBuilder().selectColumns("Kli_nip").where().eq("Kli_nazwa",et_nazwa.getText().toString()).prepare();

                    et_adres.setText(q_adres.toString());
                    et_nip.setText(q_nip.toString());
                    }
                } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

And I've got this strange error like:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prepared query is not of type SELECT_LONG, did you call QueryBuilder.setCountOf(true)?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Prepared query is not of type SELECT_LONG, did you call QueryBuilder.setCountOf(true)?

So the exception is trying to tell you what went wrong.  When you build a query, ORMLite does not know what the query is going to be used for.  Because you can select various columns and the like or use aggregate functions (like `MAX(...)`) it records an internal query-type and then checks it when the query is executed.

If you want to use `Dao.countOf(...)` then you need to add `setCountOf(true)` on your `QueryBuilder` object.  The docs for `Dao.countOf(...)` should be made more explicit of this fact.

```
PreparedQuery<Klient> query = klientDao.queryBuilder().setCountOf(true)
     .where().eq("Kli_nazwa",et_nazwa.getText().toString()).prepare();
```

If you use `queryBuilder.countOf()` or `where.countOf()` then it will set the count-of flag internally.  You can get the count of the query without this problem by doing:

```
value = klientDao.queryBuilder()
     .where().eq("Kli_nazwa",et_nazwa.getText().toString()).countOf();
```

Btw, this is a strange pattern:

```
    et_adres.setText(((PreparedQuery)q_adres).toString());
```

Maybe you wanted to do the following?

```
 String queryString = klientDao.queryBuilder()...prepareStatementString();
```

Comment: I wished myself that you take a look on it. You're just amazing man! Thanks for help !